# overflow hidden not taking effect

Tags: html, css

I am clearly using `overflow:hidden`  for floats. I've used it in header section but for some reason yet it is not taking effect and the image that I have just under the navigation lists sticks in the same row as `nav`. List and title and has reduced width for some reason.

Where did I go wrong here? I have checked and cross checked but I made sure I did not miss any tags in html and used `overflow: hidden` for `header` in CSS.

```css
/*
***************
=Header
***************
*/
header {
  overflow: hidden;
}
header h1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 23px;
  float: left;
}
/*
***************
=Navigation
***************
*/
nav {
  float: right;
}
nav li {
  display: inline;
}
/*
***************
=Banner
***************
*/
.banner {
  background: url("../img/TitleImage.jpg") no-repeat;
  /*width:1000px;*/
  height: 231px;
}
.callout {
  background: black;
  height: 231px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container_12">
  <header>
    <h1> Black + White </h1>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Services</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">How we work</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Work Examples</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="banner grid_10">
      <p>Some slick phrase would go in here to sum up .</p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_2 callout"></div>
  </header>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="grid_10">
      <div class="grid_5">
        <h1>Services we offer </h1> 
        <p>This is sample text to check the formatting and practice html with css. It seems to come easy. I wonder why I never tried it before.</p>
        <p>This is just another paragraph for testing purpose.</p>
        <p> <a href="#" class="button"> Read more </a> 
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid_5">
        <h1>How we work </h1> 
        <p>This is sample text to check the formatting and practice html with css. It seems to come easy. I wonder why I never tried it before.</p>
        <p>This is just another paragraphn for testing purpose.</p>
        <p> <a href="#" class="button"> Read more </a> 
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_2">
      <blockquote>
        <p>sample block quote goes here in the website</p>
      </blockquote>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <p> <strong>black+white</strong> themes via <a href="#"> theme forest</a> 
      </p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`overflow:hidden`, in a float clearing-context, wraps an element around all of it's floated children and subsequent siblings will appear ***after*** the element with `overflow:hidden` in the document flow.

That being said, `nav` and `.banner` appear in the same element (`header`), so applying `overflow:hidden` on `header` here will not help you achieve what you want.

Just set `.banner` to clear all floats:

`.banner { clear: both; }`

Answer (score 0):

You have two floated elements: H1 and the nav. H1 is left, nav is right. Then, of course, .callout comes after .banner and it doesnt fit into your clearing. You need to solve those 2 floats (h1 and/or nav) before containing .banner.